# Error response from daemon: Get https://ghcr.io/v2/: read tcp 10.10.5.108:33012->20.207.73.86:443: read: connection reset by peer

Tags: linux, docker, networking, huggingface, ghcr

I Can't seem to pull the text generation inference docker image

I run the command

```
docker pull ghcr.io/huggingface/text-generation-inference:sha256-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx467d7cf721f015b0987c956837f0e4f33e7b2.sig
```

and the output is

```
Error response from daemon: Get https://ghcr.io/v2/: read tcp 10.10.5.108:33012->20.207.73.86:443: read: connection reset by peer
```

is it my client side error?

I am sshing into a local dgx machine

```
ssh -L 8888:localhost:8888 dgx-user1@10.10.x.xxx
```

Expected behavior
download the image and then be able to run

```
docker run --gpus all --shm-size 1g -p 8080:80 -v $volume:/data ghcr.io/huggingface/text-generation-inference:0.9 --model-id $model --num-shard $num_shard
```